# Rare earth doping in ferrites

Tags: material-science

I have seen many papers where rare earth have been doped in ferrites . What are the properties that are changed by doing so?

Comment: They don't explain in the papers you've seen why they're doping?

Answer (score 1):

"The substitution of rare earth elements in cobalt and copper ferrite are promising for their magneto-optical recording application as they are helpful in reducing the grain size of the materials and also alter the saturation magnetization and coercivity as compared to the pure ferrite" ([Appl. Phys. A (2017) 123:312](https://scholar.cu.edu.eg/sites/default/files/drebtesam/files/cocu_rare_earth_.pdf))